# Get the value of port from docker ps command

Tags: linux, docker, unix, ps

On running docker ps command I get all the processes that are running. I have deployed MongoDB instances onto docker containers. And on giving `docker ps | grep mongo` it shows all the mongodb  instances that are running. Refer the picture for better understanding

[image]

Now I have to display the port details and it is little ambiguous, the end result should be `2040`.
Though I have come up with something which indeed gives the correct output but I am hoping for a short and more efficient way to get the port details.

This is how I am getting the o/p currently

```
docker ps | grep mongo | awk '{print $10}' | awk -F ":" '{print $2}'| cut -d '-' -f 1
```

Comment: Have you tried `docker port mongo 27017/tcp`? Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: If you look at the image - I want the value 2040 to be returned

Comment: This outputs 2040: `docker port mongo 27017/tcp | awk '{split($1,a,":"); print a[2]}'`

Answer (score 1):

do this,

```
docker ps|grep mongo|awk '{print $1}'|xargs docker inspect  --format="{{json .NetworkSettings.Ports}}"
```

Comment: It gives {"27017/tcp":[{"HostIp":"0.0.0.0","HostPort":"2040"}]} and it is too complex. I'm getting the desired output with linux awk cmd. Was hoping for a more simpler method but this looks way too complex.